# Editor eating parts of my answer

Tags: bug

In this question:

[Is it OK to run 12-3 cable to a ceiling fan from a switch that's wired with 12-2?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/37312/is-it-ok-to-run-12-3-cable-to-a-ceiling-fan-from-a-switch-thats-wired-with-12-2)

[My answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/37313/22) started out:

> Either is fine.

Scope out the [edit history](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/37313/revisions).

That was eaten (present in editing and edit preview, gone when I saved the answer/edit) at least three times before I put in the verbiage that someone else edited out along with the actual phrase, which, since that phrase was the meat of the answer was not OK; I understand the desire to "Clean things up" but cleaning them up by making the answer completely about peripheral concerns is a bad way to clean them up.

After having it eaten a fourth and fifth time, I found that **bolding it** made it stay. But it's definitely odd behavior - no funky control characters or anything else that should make the editor think I was issuing computer commands.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this: http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/a/923/22. I don't see anything about it on [metase]; let me make some inquiries.